# Is "handwriting" countable or uncountable?

Tags: countable-nouns

Which do I say?

> You have good handwriting.

or

> You have a good handwriting.

Comment: Hello Mariam, and welcome to ELL! Unfortunately, this site is for questions that you are unable to find answers to yourself. If you look up "handwriting" in any online dictionary, you'll find the answer you're looking for. If you've already done this and are still confused -- perhaps you saw it used somewhere and you think it's wrong -- then please edit your question (using the small "Edit" button under the question) to give us the quote and source

Answer (score 6):

*Handwriting* is usually uncountable, and is almost always uncountable in everyday conversation. If you are complimenting someone's handwriting, you would say

> You have good **handwriting**.

However, handwriting can be countable if you are talking about a class or general group of text that contain many different styles. For example, in Joseph B. Lightfoot's *[Essays on "Supernatural Religion"](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/18191)*, he discusses "seventh or eighth century handwritings":

> In some **handwritings** of the seventh or eighth century, where the letters have a round form, the substitution of OT for EG would be far from difficult.

The plural is appropriate here because the handwritings of the 7th and 8th centuries are varied and contain many different forms.

If you don't know whether a noun is countable, a good resource is [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org). In its [entry for handwriting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handwriting), it clearly states:

> **handwriting** (*usually uncountable, plural* handwritings)

Answer (score 1):

*handwriting* is uncountable.

> handwriting
> noun [ U ]B1 writing with a pen or pencil:
> We need to ensure that handwriting is properly taught in our primary schools.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/handwriting)

> Good is an adjective while well is an adverb answering the question how. Sometimes well also functions as an adjective pertaining to health.
> [Reference](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/adjectives-adverbs/good-v-well/)

As *handwriting* is a noun, we use *good*, an adjective.

> You have good handwriting.